# parse JSON string java, best practice

Tags: java, json, parsing, getjson

I have JSON string/response and I need simple parse it and get objects/arrays, it can be repeated, so I need get list by list, actually I do not know how to do it, because a lot of parsers and all examples with simple JSON-es, but my is bit difficult and I need to navigate in it.
Here is a example of my JSON

```
{
    "HotelListResponse": {
        "customerSessionId": "0ABAAA83-04C7-5B91-40A2-754D7299476C",
        "numberOfRoomsRequested": 1,
        "moreResultsAvailable": true,
        "cacheKey": "-4804c75b:140a754d729:4da2",
        "cacheLocation": "10.186.170.131:7300",
        "HotelList": {
            "@activePropertyCount": "1157",
            "@size": "1",
            "HotelSummary": {
                "@order": "0",
                "hotelId": 403147,
                "name": "Justabed - Hostel",
                "address1": "38 avenue augustin dumont",
                "city": "Malakoff",
                "postalCode": 92240,
                "countryCode": "FR",
                "airportCode": "   ",
                "supplierType": "E",
                "propertyCategory": 5,
                "hotelRating": 0,
                "confidenceRating": 52,
                "amenityMask": 8,
                "tripAdvisorRating": 1.5,
                "locationDescription": "Near Paris Expo Porte de Versailles",
                "shortDescription": "&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Property Location&lt;/b&gt; &lt;br /&gt;With a stay at Justabed in Vanves, you&apos;ll be close to Stade de la Plaine and Eiffel Tower.&lt;br/&gt; This hostel is within close proximity of Georges Brassens Park and",
                "highRate": 24.87,
                "lowRate": 24.87,
                "rateCurrencyCode": "EUR",
                "latitude": 48.81804,
                "longitude": 2.30196,
                "proximityDistance": 2.5680416,
                "proximityUnit": "MI",
                "hotelInDestination": true,
                "thumbNailUrl": "/hotels/5000000/4850000/4849100/4849100/4849100_7_t.jpg",
                "deepLink": "http://travel.ian.com/index.jsp?pageName=hotAvail&amp;cid=55505&amp;hotelID=403147&amp;mode=2&amp;numberOfRooms=1&amp;room-0-adult-total=1&amp;room-0-child-total=0&amp;arrivalMonth=8&amp;arrivalDay=18&amp;departureMonth=8&amp;departureDay=21&amp;showInfo=true&amp;locale=en_US&amp;currencyCode=EUR",
                "RoomRateDetailsList": {
                    "RoomRateDetails": {
                        "roomTypeCode": 200166353,
                        "rateCode": 201887482,
                        "maxRoomOccupancy": 1,
                        "quotedRoomOccupancy": 1,
                        "minGuestAge": 3,
                        "roomDescription": "Single Beds in Mixed Dormitory Room - Non refundable",
                        "currentAllotment": 8,
                        "propertyAvailable": true,
                        "propertyRestricted": false,
                        "expediaPropertyId": 4849100,
                        "rateKey": "0ABAAA83-04C7-5B91-40A2-754D72994DA3",
                        "RateInfo": {
                            "@rateChange": "false",
                            "@promo": "false",
                            "@priceBreakdown": "true",
                            "ChargeableRateInfo": {
                                "@total": "79.83",
                                "@surchargeTotal": "5.22",
                                "@nightlyRateTotal": "74.61",
                                "@maxNightlyRate": "24.87",
                                "@currencyCode": "EUR",
                                "@commissionableUsdTotal": "99.65",
                                "@averageRate": "24.87",
                                "@averageBaseRate": "24.87",
                                "NightlyRatesPerRoom": {
                                    "@size": "3",
                                    "NightlyRate": [
                                        {
                                            "@promo": "false",
                                            "@rate": "24.87",
                                            "@baseRate": "24.87"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "@promo": "false",
                                            "@rate": "24.87",
                                            "@baseRate": "24.87"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "@promo": "false",
                                            "@rate": "24.87",
                                            "@baseRate": "24.87"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "Surcharges": {
                                    "@size": "1",
                                    "Surcharge": {
                                        "@amount": "5.22",
                                        "@type": "TaxAndServiceFee"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "ValueAdds": {
                            "@size": "1",
                            "ValueAdd": {
                                "@id": "2048",
                                "description": "Free Wireless Internet"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There was a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1710231/864571

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I summarized and used jackson
here is a answer, maybe it will usefull for another people

```
 public void parseLink(String jsonObject) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonFactory factory = mapper.getJsonFactory(); // since 2.1 use mapper.getFactory() instead
            JsonParser jp = factory.createJsonParser(jsonObject);
            JsonNode input = mapper.readTree(jp);

         //   final JsonNode results = input.get("HotelListResponse").get("HotelList").get("HotelSummary");

            Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> nodeIterator = input.get("HotelListResponse").getFields();

            while (nodeIterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = (Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>) nodeIterator.next();
                System.out.println("key --> " + entry.getKey() + " value-->" + entry.getValue());

            }

           Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> nodeIterator1 = input.get("HotelListResponse").get("HotelList").getFields();

            while (nodeIterator1.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = (Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>) nodeIterator1.next();
                System.out.println("key --> " + entry.getKey() + " value-->" + entry.getValue());

            }

            Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> nodeIterator2 = input.get("HotelListResponse").get("HotelList").get("HotelSummary").getFields();

            while (nodeIterator2.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = (Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>) nodeIterator2.next();
                System.out.println("key --> " + entry.getKey() + " value-->" + entry.getValue());

            }




        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HotelBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 libraries that I know for parsing JSON in Java : GSON and Jackson. I know a little about Jackson and it works in 3 ways :

1. You can ask Jackson to parse your JSON into an object
2. You can read your JSON and load it in memory, so you can navigate in it.
3. You can read your JSON like a stream

Here is the link about these ways : http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a library for this, something like http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/ (others are out there; that's just the first one I found with a web search.)

Unless of course, this is a school project or something and you need to write your own parser. In that case, perhaps you should come up with a more specific question and ask that instead of asking how to do everything.